# How to SHOW COLUMNS exclude 1 or more Columns in Laravel SQL select?

Tags: jquery, laravel, eloquent

How is it possible to show columns and exclude 1 or more specific Fields?

I already tried

```
DB::select( "SHOW COLUMNS FROM tbl LIKE '%". $search . "%' AND WHERE Field != '". $selected ."'" );
```

I want to create a dynamic page that user can show any Columns what they want. I want to remove if the data is already appended or selected.

Here is my HTML & jQuery.

```
<ul></ul>
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="search here">
<div id="data">
    <a href="#" class="addMe" data-id="{{ $columnName }}">
        <strong>{{ $columnName }}</strong>
    </a>
</div>

// jQuery
$(document).on('keyup', '#search', function(){
    var query = $(this).val();
    
    // Ajax get data
})
.on('click', '.addMe', function() {
    var remove = $(this).data('id');
    
    $('ul').append(`
            <li class="${remove}">
                <h3 class="col-name">${remove}</h3>
            </li>
        `)

    // Ajax get data
});
```

If there is any missing or unclear statement, just ask me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Helper functions in laravel will solve your problem. you can use `except()`, `pluck()`, `map()` on the collections

Comment: I already tried except() but still error, `Call to a member function except() on array`. Do you have any example on how deal with it?

Comment: Or else Array Values in WHERE CLAUSE? like `WHERE Fields = $array`, is this possible?